# Как генерировать токен при входе и удалять при выходе?

Tags: java, android, android-notification, fcm

Использую FCM для пуш уведомлений. Как генерировать токен при определенном событии? Как правильно привязать токен к аккаунту? Расскажите общий принцип. Я что-то совсем не смог разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты не можешь насильно генерировать токены, они привязываются к девайсу и генерируются при первой логинизации юзера или по необходимости сервисов гугл.В любос случае нужно написать класс который extend-ит FirebaseInstanceIdService и в нем по вызову метода onTokenRefresh (он всегда вызывается при смене токена) записывать токен в SharedPreferences и/или отсылать на свой backend.

Все очень доходчиво расписано тут: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: На самом деле могу ) я удаляю и потом сново генерирую токен и сохраняю в префенсах .Не совсем удобно но очень рабоче

Comment: скорее всего тебе возвращается тот же токен который ты удалил, если юзер не перелогинился или FCM сам не перегенерирует токен

Comment: нет токен генерится новый .Я проверил через compareto